# AutoMapper Get All Profiles Non static API version

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I want to convert this to new version.
I Read:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x => GetConfiguration(Mapper.Configuration));
    }

    private static void GetConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
        {
            var profiles = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x != typeof(Profile) && typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(x));
            foreach (var profile in profiles)
            {
                configuration.AddProfile((Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(profile));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My configuration files in /Plugins/plugin-name/Entities/Config folder with the name of my EntityConfiguration
And my view data is in /Plugins/plugin-name/ViewModels/EntityEditViewModel

Thank you!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I convert this to new version.

Comment: The first example on the first link you posted shows how to add profiles to the configuration.

Comment: It doesn't show how to do automatticly. I have to add by hand. each of them